# How to recursively link javascript files to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following file structure:

```
root - dir1 - js_dir     - file.js  
     - dir2 - inner_dir  - header.php
```

The directory **js_dir** contains my javascript files. I'm trying to recursively add them to my header in `header.php` as follows:

**header.php**

```
<head>
    <?php

        $dir = '../../dir1';

        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

        foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
          if ($path->isDir()) {
            print('<div> DIR : ' . $path . PHP_EOL . "</div>");
          } else {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
            $file_parts = $path_parts['extension'];
            if ($file_parts == "js")
            {
              $array = explode("/opt/lampp/htdocs", $path);
              unset($array[0]);
              echo $path = implode("/", $array);
              print("<div>http://localhost$path" . PHP_EOL . "</div>");
              echo("<script src='http://localhost/$path'></script>");
            }
          }
        }

        ?>
</head>
```

I, however, keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(../js): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/root
```

How can I go about getting it to work?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: should be `../../dir1`

Comment: I would probably choose some file-index based solution as it's much cleaner.

Comment: Sorry @CodeGodie. That was a mistake I did while shortening my Code.

Comment: What is the absolute path to dir1?  Oh, according to your breakdown it's a subdirectory of root.  So why are you using '../../dir1' instead of './dir1'?

Comment: the problem its that relative paths change depending on where youre currently on.. If you are planning on including the header.php elsewhere  you might have these issues as whatever youre including it on will most likely not be in the same path. I would hardcode a constat called ROOT_DIR and give it the absolute path of your root folder. You can then use that to access your files.